# How to NOT nest a button in Vue js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

So i have a button that i want to use multiple times, made as component with a slot

```
<div
      name="checkAnswer"
      class="w-[70%] mx-[15%] flex items-center justify-center"
    >
      <button
        class="p-3 rounded-3xl shadow-md font-bold m-4 px-10 border-2 border-grey-800 hover:border-black hover:transition-all hover:duration-500"
      >
        <slot name="checkAnswer"></slot>
      </button>
    </div>
```

But when i want to use it, i cant make @click="method" on slot button, so i use a nested button (i have a slot button and then another button just to use @click="method"):

```
 <template #checkAnswer>
        <button
          @click="checkAnswer"
          :disabled="isAnswerChecked"
          :class="{
            ' text-gray-300 border-gray-300  ': isAnswerChecked,
          }"
        >
          Check answer
        </button>
      </template>
```

which works but it is invalid html. How do i solve it?

Comment: what vue version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Vue3 SFC Playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

You need to bind the button component's attributes to the `<button>` in the template with `v-bind="$attrs"` and disable default attribute inheritance to the template's root element with `inheritAttrs:false`.

Also you don't need a named slot here, use just a default one:

```
<script>
export default {
  inheritAttrs: false, // This is what disables attribute inheritance
};
</script>
<template>
<div
      name="checkAnswer"
      class="w-[70%] mx-[15%] flex items-center justify-center"
    >
      <button v-bind="$attrs"
        class="p-3 rounded-3xl shadow-md font-bold m-4 px-10 border-2 border-grey-800 hover:border-black hover:transition-all hover:duration-500"
      >
        <slot></slot>
      </button>
    </div>
</template>
```

The parent component:

```
<script setup>
import MyButton from './MyButton.vue';
import {ref} from 'vue';
const isAnswerChecked = ref(false);

const checkAnswer = () => {
  alert('check answer!');
  isAnswerChecked.value = true;
};

</script>
<template>
<MyButton @click="checkAnswer"
          :disabled="isAnswerChecked"
          :class="{
            ' text-gray-300 border-gray-300  ': isAnswerChecked,
          }"
        >
          Check answer
      </MyButton>
</template>
```

Comment: thanks sir for provided answer and your time! i will try this solution!